# Getting a list of live stream sources connected to Wowza

Tags: android, rest, wowza

I am developing and android video live streaming App with Wowza streaming engine media server (4.5).
I want to get a list of live stream sources connected to Wowza, and display them in a list-view.
In the Wowza docs, I found the Wowza Streaming Engine REST API, and an implementation example:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/publishers
```

How do I use the Wowza REST API in android?

A small example or any steps would be helpful.

Comment: welcome to SO! :-)
i removed some tags, as people specializing in those would not be able to help you with this question.
your did very well for a first question!
just maybe learn how to format a question (quoting, code formatting, ...). more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
ride on!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
curl -X GET  --digest  -u admin:admin --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' [http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/*defaultServer*/publishers](http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/publishers)
For reference: 
https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?49599-cURL-request-quot-requires-user-authentication-quot-start-stop-live-streams-every-M-9-50

Answer (score 0):

Wowza Streaming engine provides some inbuilt Rest API that can used to fetch the current statics of the incoming streams to your streaming engine.

You can curl it as:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/instances/_definst_/incomingstreams/myStream/monitoring/current
```